# How can I locally clone opneshift application or clone it to git

Tags: git, openshift, redhat

Command:

```
git clone ssh://56e441dasfasfasfas341d000061@aw2d1164-atpict.rhcloud.com/~/git/age345.git/
```

Error:

```
Cloning into 'awsd007'...

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What's that and how to fix it?

Comment: Please copy the error message here. Or at least fix the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question, please check.

Comment: Aha, that's better. Let's look. Are you sure user `56e441dasfasfasfas341d000061` has ssh access to host `aw2d1164-atpict.rhcloud.com`? Where from did you get the command?

Comment: I just googled the command, it says on my openshift account pass the following url to git clone to clone the repository locally, I copied the url and did git clone url on my terminal....suggest me what should I do instead

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't create a `ssh key`, check this website for more information:

https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Also its probably better and easier if you use `https` intsead of `ssh`

Comment: But would it get me the complete code and all the files in Database locally?

Comment: No it will not get out local files from the data directory or anything in a database. For some tips on getting data out of V2, read https://blog.openshift.com/migrating-your-applications-from-openshift-2-to-3/